# jQuery .delegate() on multiple elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

When using the `.delegate` can I choose multiple elements or should I have to use `.delegate` for every element that I need to work with? (function will be the same for all elements)

e.g.

```
$('#div').delegate('a', 'click' (function(){ // This is ok
         .delegate('a, element_2, element_3', 'click' (function(){ // IS THIS OK??
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is fine since `'a, element_2, element_3'` is a valid selector, which is the first argument of [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

BUT, your arguments are not separated by commas properly, it should be:

```
$('#div').delegate('a, element_2, element_3', 'click', function(){
    //function go here
});
```

Comment: And just to drive it home, [all appears to be well](http://jsfiddle.net/XeTSj/1/).

Answer (score 1):

That second method appears to be **okay** as it `a, element_1, element_2` returns a set of elements that will have the `.delegate()` function applied.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is OK, the documentation states

```
.delegate( selector, events )
```

Selector being any valid jQuery selector. even your first call may return more than one element.